# @selector with multiple arguments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

How does one call an @selector method with multiple arguments?

I have the following

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeImage:withString:) withObject:A1 withObject:fileString2 afterDelay:0.1];
```

but get an

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

error

My method I am calling is as follows

```
-(void) changeImage: (UIButton *) button withString: (NSString *) string
{
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:string] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use NSInvocation

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                             [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(changeImage:withString:)]];
[invocation setTarget:self];
[invocation setSelector:@selector(changeImage:withString:)];
[invocation setArgument:A1 atIndex:2];
[invocation setArgument:fileString2 atIndex:3];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. How do I call it. I want to call this in a lot of places. So can it be declared in the viewDidLoad method and then be called in various places?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. You can put this piece of code anywhere in the class where changeImage:withString: is defined. If you want to call it multiple times, you should wrap it in a method and call that method instead.

Comment: alternately, you can do `[invocation performSelector:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];`

Answer (score 4):

The NSObject class has a `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method, and the NSObject protocol specifies a `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` method, but nowhere is there specified a `performSelector:withObject:withObject:afterDelay:`.

In this case, you'll have to use an [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get the functionality you desire. Set up the invocation, and then you can call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` on the invocation itself, using the selector `invoke` and a `nil` object.

Answer (score 3):

There is no method for performing a selector with multiple arguments *and* a delay. You could wrap the button and the string object in a NSDictionary to work around this like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:A1,@"button",fileString2,@"string",nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(changeWithDict:) withObject:dict afterDelay:0.1];
//...

-(void)changeWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    [[dict objectForKey:@"button"] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"string"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting iOS 4.0+ you could use blocks. Something along the lines of this should do the trick.

```
// Delay execution of my block for 0.1 seconds.
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, USEC_PER_SEC / 10ull), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    [self changeImage:A1 withString:fileString2];
});
```

Comment: In that case you need to be using the NSInvocation method provided by others. Blocks were only introduced in iOS 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good way to get round it, but if you wanted you could modify the method to accept an NSArray, when the object at index 0 is the button and at index 1 is the string.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `performSelector:withObject:withObject:afterDelay:`, but that method doesn't exist.

Your only option is `performSelector:withObject:withObject:`, but you can't specify a delay with that method. If you need a delay, you'd probably have to create a category for `NSObject` and create a new method yourself.